# How to deduce an expression of a specific conditional expression

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, economics

The problem occurs when reading [Bombardini et al., 2023, "Did US Politicians Expect the China Shock?", *American Economic Review*, Vol.1, PP174-209](https://bcf.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/BLT25jan2021.pdf).

The authors define $\xi_{it}$ to be a Gaussian term obeying $N(0,2\sigma_{\xi}^2)$ (*see line 7, page 7 in the link*), and $Y_{i,t} = \mathbf{1}\{a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}]\geq\xi_{it}\}$ (*see equation 4, page 8*). To my understand, $a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}]$ can be seen as a constant once $\mathcal{I}$ is given.

I do not know how, but the authors manage to show that

$$-E[Y_{i,t}\xi_{i,t}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}]=(1-Y_{i,t})\frac{\phi(a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}])}{1-\Phi(a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}])},$$
where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are respectively the distribution function and density function of the standard normal distribution (*see equation (13), page 12 in the link*).

Can anyone explain to me in detail? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://bcf.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/BLT25jan2021.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiw-vnD-fqEAxV7gv0HHRhoAOAQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1f7-PenNBzISda_bwZAH5e)? If yes, ask a more detailed question by mentioning the page, line, etc.

Comment: @callculus42 I've edited the question. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this proof is complete and correct, but I would like to share what I have attempted.

Let $z\in\mathbb{R}$, then it holds
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}-\mathbb{1}_{\{z\ge x\}}x\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x)
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}-\mathbb{1}_{\{z\ge x\}}x\phi(x)\ dx\\
&=\phi(z)\\
&=\frac{\phi(z)}{1-\Phi(z)}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_{\{z<x\}}\phi(x)\ dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}(1-\mathbb{1}_{\{z\ge x\}})\frac{\phi(z)}{1-\Phi(z)}\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x).
\end{aligned}
$$

Applying Fubini's theorem for conditional expectations yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}E[-\mathbb{1}_{\{Z\ge x\}}x|\mathcal{G}]\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x)
&=E[\int_{\mathbb{R}}-\mathbb{1}_{\{Z\ge x\}}x\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x)|\mathcal{G}]\\
&=E[\int_\mathbb{R}(1-\mathbb{1}_{\{Z\ge x\}})\frac{\phi(Z)}{1-\Phi(Z)}\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x)|\mathcal{G}]\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}E[(1-\mathbb{1}_{\{Z\ge x\}})\frac{\phi(Z)}{1-\Phi(Z)}|\mathcal{G}]\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
for a random variable $Z$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$.

You then might want to choose $Z:=a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}]$ and $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{I}_{i,t}$ to find
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}E[-Y_{i,t}x|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}]\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x) 
&= \int_\mathbb{R}(1-Y_{i,t})\frac{\phi(a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}])}{1-\Phi(a_{t}\theta_{i}+b_{t}+\delta_{t} E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}])}\ d\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x).\\
\end{aligned}
$$

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could provide additional feedback on whether this is sufficient and accurate. (The problem I am facing is that both $E[S_{i,t+1}|\mathcal{I}_{i,t}]$ and $\xi_{i,t}$ should end up having the same $\omega$ as an argument.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why the expectation symbol $E[|\mathcal{G}]$ in the right-hand-side integral disappears after you substitute $Z$ and $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: $(1-\mathbb{1}_{\{Z\ge x\}})\frac{\phi(Z)}{1-\Phi(Z)}$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable for each $x$, if $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Comment: But it seems to me that $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{Z\geq x\}}|\mathcal{G}]$ cannot be simplified to $Y_{i,t}$, since the former one is a constant, but the latter one is still a random variable even when $\mathcal{G}$ is given?

Comment: In the integral equation itself, $x$ is a real number which gets integrated along $\mu_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. As I stated, I am not sure, if this integral equation is enough to show the desired result. It seems like one might need another result on parameter integrals. I hope someone comes along and clarifies the details.