# The Laplace transform of a conditional random variable

Tags: conditional-probability, laplace-transform, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with mean $1$ and $q \in (0,1)$. Define the random variable $Y \triangleq (1-q)X + q$. Now, the CCDF of Y is given by $\mathbb{P}(Y>y) = e^{-\frac{y-q}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(y\geq q) +\mathbf{1}(y<q)$, where $\mathbf{1}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function. Let $Z>0$ be a random variable. I claim that the following statements are both valid:
$$             
                 (1) \hspace{0.5cm} \mathbb{P}(Y> Z) = {\mathbb{E}} \left[ e^{-\frac{Z-q}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(Z\geq q)+\mathbf{1}(Z<q) \right]=
{\mathbb{E}} \left[ e^{-\frac{Z-q}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(Z\geq q)\right]+\mathbb{P}(Z<q),
$$
$$           
                 (2) \hspace{0.5cm} \mathbb{P}(Y> Z) = {\mathbb{E}} \left[ e^{-\frac{(Z|(Z \geq q))-q}{1-q}}\right]\mathbb{P}(Z\geq q) +\mathbb{P}(Z<q),
$$
with the conditional random variable $(Z|(Z \geq q))$.

The title of the post is because combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ would follow

$$
\mathcal{L}_{(Z|(Z \geq q))}\left( \frac{1}{1-q}\right)\triangleq{\mathbb{E}} \left[ e^{-\frac{(Z|(Z \geq q))}{1-q}}\right] = \frac{{\mathbb{E}} \left[ e^{-\frac{Z}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(Z\geq q)\right] }{\mathbb{P}(Z\geq q)}.
$$

For me, both (1) and (2) are valid in their logical sense. However, I struggle to formally derive (2) from (1) or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of mathematical rigor, there are two primary concerns regarding your assertions:

**1.** The assertion only holds if we assume $Z$ to be independent of $Y$ (and, consequently, of $X$). Take, for instance, $Z = Y$. Then the stated equalities don't hold true.

**2.** The term "conditional random variable" lacks a precise definition in mathematical terms. Generally, for any event $E$ with $\mathbb{P}(E) > 0$, it's not possible to "conditionalize" a random variable $Z$ (by means of processing $Z$ as a quantity) in such a way that all associated probabilistic quantities (like the distribution of $Z$ or joint distributions involving $Z$) are "conditionalized" in a compatible manner. For this reason, people do not bother to define the notion of conditional random variable.

Rather than attempting to manipulate the random variable itself, a more natural and neat solution is to replace the probability law $\mathbb{P}$ by the conditional probability law $\mathbb{P}(\cdot \mid E)$.

---

In light of this discussion, now we can properly adjust the assertions and prove them rigorously.

Suppose $X$ is an exponential RV under $\mathbb{P}$ with mean $1$. Fix $q \in (0, 1)$ and define $Y = (1-q)X + q$. As OP has already observed, the CCDF $\tilde{F}_Y$ of $Y$ is given by

$$ \tilde{F}_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y > y) = e^{-\frac{y-q}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(y \geq q) + \mathbf{1}(y < q). $$

Also, let $Z$ be a positive RV independent of $Y$. Then by the law of iterated expectation,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y > Z)
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(Y > Z \mid Z)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\tilde{F}_Y(Z)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-\frac{Z-q}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(Z \geq q) + \mathbf{1}(Z < q) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-\frac{Z-q}{1-q}}\mathbf{1}(Z \geq q) \right] + \mathbb{P}(Z < q),
\end{align*}

proving $(1)$. Moreover, if $\mathbb{P}(Z \geq q) > 0$, then by noting that $\mathbb{E}[ \square \mid Z \geq q] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[ \square \mathbf{1}(Z \geq q)]}{\mathbb{P}(Z \geq q)}$ for any placeholder RV $\square$, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y > Z)
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-\frac{Z-q}{1-q}} \,\middle|\, Z \geq q \right] \mathbb{P}(Z \geq q) + \mathbb{P}(Z < q).
\end{align*}

Now note that the distribution of $Z$ under $\mathbb{P}(\cdot \mid Z \geq q)$ is precisely the conditional distribution $Z \mid (Z \geq q)$ under $\mathbb{P}$, part $\text{(2)}$ is also established.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Indeed, I assumed independence but forgot to mention it. I think the key is here the equality  $\mathbb{E}[\square|Z \geq q] = \mathbb{E}[\square \mathbf{1}(Z\geq q)]/\mathbb{P}(Z\geq q)$ , which is not clear to me.

Comment: @Mundo, By definition, $\mathbb{E}[W\mid Z\geq q]$ is the expectation of a random variable $W$ with respect to the probability law $\mathbb{P}(\cdot \mid Z\geq q)$. Now, for any event $A$, we know that $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(A) \mid Z\geq q]=\mathbb{P}(A \mid Z\geq q)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap \{Z\geq q\})}{\mathbb{P}(Z\geq q)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(A)\cdot\mathbf{1}(Z\geq q)]}{\mathbb{P}(Z\geq q)}.$$ By a standard machinery in probability theory, this is enough to conclude that $$\mathbb{E}[W\mid Z\geq q]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[W\cdot\mathbf{1}(Z\geq q)]}{\mathbb{P}(Z\geq q)}$$ for any $W$.

Comment: In short, the reason is because the corresponding identity holds for probabilities.

Comment: @SangchulLee Could you please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4888566? It is a similar question, which you possibly can contribute to. Thank you!